# Display loading animation in button while AsyncTask, blocks UI

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-animation

I'm trying to implement a button that when it's pressed, changes its image with a loading spinner. Here is the code to accomplish that:

```
mButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.loading_spinner, 0);
Drawable progressAnimationLeft = mButton.getCompoundDrawables()[2];
Animatable animatable = ((Animatable) progressAnimationLeft);
animatable.start();
```

**loading_spinner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:fromDegrees="720"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toDegrees="0"
/>
```

This works perfectly

[image: Idle button]

[image: Loading]

And displays the animation correctly.

Now, I have to add the time consuming task, which I added using an AsyncTask.

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.loading_spinner, 0);
        Drawable progressAnimationLeft = mButton.getCompoundDrawables()[2];
        Animatable animatable = ((Animatable) progressAnimationLeft);
        animatable.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // Time consuming work
        timeConsumingMethod();
        return null;
    }
};

task.execute();
```

But in this case, the animation displays the spinner icon but then stops until the timeConsumingMethod finishes.

I have read that probably I need to use `ProgressBar` instead of this approach. I am missing something here?

Comment: Which android platform version is this? I wouldn't put it beyond some previous versions to re-use the same thread for AsyncTasks and animations ...

Comment: Asynctask block UI when you use preexecute and postexecute, you can call an AlerDialog or startanimation, after call the Asynctask without preexexute an in postexecute stop animation if this was started.

Comment: @dhke the app is minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21